# Component VDatepicker from VCalendor not showing date in V-TextField - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Component VDatepicker from VCalendor not showing date in V-TextField - VueJS

I'm developing an application using VueJS with Vuetify in FrontEnd. When using the VDatePicker component of https://vcalendar.io/, with the V-Text-Field Slot from Vuetify, when selecting the date, it is not sent date selected to the V-TextField. I need the label in the text-field, and when I select the date in the VDatePicker, it only shows the component's label in the V-Text_field. How to resolve this so that it can show the date in the text-field?

Meu app.js

```
import './bootstrap';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import { setupCalendar, Calendar, DatePicker } from 'v-calendar';
import 'v-calendar/style.css';

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
})

const myCustomLightTheme = {
    dark: false,
    colors: {
        background: '#CCCCCC',
        surface: '#FFFFFF',
        primary: '#6200EE',
        'primary-darken-1': '#3700B3',
        secondary: '#03DAC6',
        'secondary-darken-1': '#018786',
        error: '#B00020',
        info: '#2196F3',
        success: '#4CAF50',
        warning: '#FB8C00',
    },
}

export default createVuetify({
    theme: {
        defaultTheme: 'myCustomLightTheme',
        themes: {
            myCustomLightTheme,
        },
    },
})

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', { eager: true })
        return pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]
    },
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(vuetify)
            .use(setupCalendar, {})
            .component('VCalendar', Calendar)
            .component('VDatePicker', DatePicker)
            .mount(el)
    },
})
```

My Component.vue

```
<script setup>
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import Layout from '../Layout/Layout.vue';
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'
import { ref } from 'vue';

const date = ref(new Date());

const props = defineProps({
    employes: Object,
   
});
</script>
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
      <VDatePicker v-model="date">
        <template #default="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
          <v-text-field type="date" :value="inputValue" v-on="inputEvents" variant="outlined" density="compact" label="Data Inicial"></v-text-field>
        </template>
      </VDatePicker>
    </v-col>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Help me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be shown in your console.  At least it's clearly shown to me when I run your code

> The specified value "07/14/2023" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

And this issue repeats with every date value.  The wording is clear though, the `inputValue` from VDatePicker does not match the format expected by the v-text-field.  You just need to convert to the expected format

```js
function format(val) {
  if (!val) return
  return new Date(val).toISOString().split('T')[0] // returns val in yyyy-mm-dd date format
}
```

```html
<VDatePicker v-model="date">
  <template #default="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
    <v-text-field
      type="date"
      :value="format(inputValue)"
      variant="outlined"
      density="compact"
      label="Data Inicial"
      v-on="inputEvents"
    ></v-text-field>
  </template>
</VDatePicker>
```